# Looking for an interval date occurence in another table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I am working with pandas dataframes in python, and I have a table (df_aux) which looks like this:

| Volume code | from_date | to_date | Volume_1 | Volume_2 | Volume_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:59:59 | 8 | 4 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 2022-01-01 01:59:59 | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 02:00:00 | 2022-01-01 02:59:59 | 10 | 9 | 14 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 03:00:00 | 2022-01-01 03:59:59 | 5 | 11 | 3 |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 04:00:00 | 2022-01-01 04:59:59 | 13 | 2 | 1 |

This is a pivoted table, which records occurrences happening in different volumes and time intervals (1 hour bin, constant)

I have another table (df_main) like this:

| Volume | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Volume_1 | 2022-01-01 04:14:00 |
| Volume_3 | 2022-01-03 02:22:00 |
| Volume_1 | 2022-01-06 12:12:00 |
| Volume_2 | 2022-03-01 08:53:00 |
| Volume_2 | 2022-05-02 09:34:00 |

I need to know the ocurrences happening in the **previous hour** of Date, in the corresponding volume. In the first row of df_main, we have an event at 04:14:00 in Volume_1. One hour earlier is 03:14:00, which in df_aux corresponds to 5 occurrences, so we would append a new column in df_main which would be 'ocurrences_1h_prev' and would take the value 5. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape `df_aux` with `.melt()` and use [`.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to search for the nearest dates.

```
df_merge = pd.merge_asof(
   df_main, 
   df_aux.melt(id_vars=['Volume code', 'from_date', 'to_date'], 
               var_name='Volume', 
               value_name='occurrences_1h_prev')
         .sort_values('to_date'),
   by='Volume',
   left_on='Date',
   right_on='to_date'
)
```

Empty out the value if - 1hour does not fall within the range:

```
df_merge.loc[
   ~df_merge['Date']
       .sub(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
       .between(df_merge['from_date'], df_merge['to_date']), 
    'occurrences_1h_prev'
] = pd.NA
```

```
>>> df_merge[['Volume', 'Date', 'occurrences_1h_prev']]
     Volume                Date  occurrences_1h_prev
0  Volume_1 2022-01-01 04:14:00                  5.0
1  Volume_3 2022-01-03 02:22:00                  NaN
2  Volume_1 2022-01-06 12:12:00                  NaN
3  Volume_2 2022-03-01 08:53:00                  NaN
4  Volume_2 2022-05-02 09:34:00                  NaN
```

Comment: Thx, this gives me the error "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" in the "Use the name in the Volume column to extract the corresponding values:" step

Comment: @datadatadata Okay. I suppose it's simpler to `.melt()` `df_aux` instead, updated.

Comment: Could you provide an example for these dfs? I'm starting with pandas...

Comment: @datadatadata What do you mean? It's `df_aux` and `df_main` from your example.

Comment: Indeed, I mean if you can edit your answer to use melt()

Comment: @datadatadata I did...